# How can I fix empty environment-variable PATH on remote machine when using ssh/scp?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, scp

When using scp to a remote machine i mysteriously got the error "sh: scp: No such file or directory":

```
$ scp admin@192.168.1.11:test.txt .
Welcome to remotehost!
admin@192.168.1.11's password: 
sh: scp: No such file or directory
```

When trying to look en the environment variables on the remote machine it also failed with "sh: env: No such file or director":

```
$ ssh admin@192.168.1.11 env
Welcome to remotehost!
admin@192.168.1.11's password: 
sh: env: No such file or director
```

But when using full path to env I could see that PATH is empty:

```
$ ssh admin@192.168.1.11 "/usr/bin/env"
Welcome to remotehost!
admin@192.168.1.11's password: 
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.7 62675 192.168.1.11 22
USER=admin
PWD=/root
HOME=/root
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.7 62675 22
MAIL=/var/mail/admin
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=admin
PATH=
_=/usr/bin/env
```

However if I log on to the machine via ssh, the PATH is not empty:

```
$ ssh admin@192.168.1.11
Welcome to remotehost!
admin@192.168.1.11's password: 
[root@ remotehost ~]# env
HOSTNAME= remotehost
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
USER=root
PAGER=/usr/bin/less
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/root
HOME=/root
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.7 62724 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/mail/admin
TERM=linux
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
PS1=[\u@\h \W]\$ 
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I also tried using root and get the same "sh: env: No such file or directory":

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.11 env
Welcome to remotehost!
root@192.168.1.11's password: 
sh: env: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix the empty environment-variable PATH?

localhost is macOS and remote is BuildRoot (https://buildroot.org) on a Raspberry

Comment: You login as admin, but get logged on as root -- how come? Maybe that doesn't work with scp or just executing a remote command?

Comment: @vlumi, I also tried using root and got the same result: "sh: env: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

This is related to login shell and non-login shell setup. Typically login shell will read from `.profile` and non-login shell will read from `.bashrc`. To fix it, you need to define the `PATH` in these configuration files.

Here are some references and explanation:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc
- https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc

Comment: I have both .bashrc,  .profile and .bash_profile in the home directory and they all define the PATH but it still doesn't work. When running env on the remote machine it says "SHELL=/bin/sh". It seems that it is not using bash. Could this be the problem?